# Black objects on screen in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am working on a game  and this is what happens in the game scene. [image]

I verified the shader on each piece dozens of times, but it is ok. In the picture you can see the debug messages with the color, emission and albedo on the materials, and they are ok. 
Any ideas what the problem could be? Any suggestion is ok because the release day is coming.

EDIT:

```
Properties {
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)  
_Cube ("Cubemap", CUBE) = "" {}
  _Emission ("Emission", Range (0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5
  _Albedo("Albedo", Range (0.01, 1)) = 0.9

}
SubShader {
  Tags {"RenderType" = "Opaque" }

  //Blend Off

  Cull Off

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma surface surf Lambert approxview noforwardadd

  fixed4 _Color;

  struct Input 
  {
      half3 worldRefl;
  };

  samplerCUBE _Cube;

  float _Emission;

  float _Albedo;

  void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
      o.Albedo = _Color.rgb * _Albedo;
      o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * _Emission;

  }

  ENDCG
} 
Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: What is the shader? Did you write it? If so, show it.

Comment: Quick question: do you have a light in your scene?

Comment: It also works for me. But in tests it happens from time to time but with no specific reproduction steps. I am also reading this http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/195328-Black-textures-on-some-devices-android-versions .

Comment: If I have to guess, I'd say you either have no lights in your scene (or none that affect the geometry) and no ambient light. That would cause the Albedo to not have any color.

Comment: I do have a light in the scene.

Comment: Then check if they are in range. The only way I can reproduce what you're seeing is by having no ambient (black) and lights turned off or moved out of range.

Comment: I also thought about the lights in the first place but the problem is not always. In testing it appears once every a couple of hours of playing.

Answer (score 0):

Try making "main color" brighter. That could potentially solve it.

[image]

Comment: This is not the problem. The "Main Color" property is brighter. The "Color" text in the debug messages is written with the"Main color" (red, blue, yellow, white).